# Determining which EditEvent is fired BEFORE feature is created

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.0, add-in

I have written an AddIn-Tool and want to handle the OnSketchFinished-Event.
The Way

```
((IEditEvents_event)_myEditSketch).OnSketchFinished += OnFinishedSketch;
```

doesn't really work for me, cause I need the get the event before the feature is created.
I rather need something like the OnFinishSketch that was fired by the IEditTask.

How do I solve this problem?